# How should I use Recurrent Neural Network to model this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I am using Keras to do a machine learning task:

Let's say I want to predict the time that a user spends on a product page. 
Each training case is a partial user visit session. One single user may have multiple sessions. The lengths of sessions are variable.

The figure shows a user session. `Xn` is the feature vector of the `n`th product page, while `yn` is the user's reading time on the product page. Given the previous time steps, I want to predict the time that the user will spend on the current page.

For example, in the test dataset, given `X1`, `X2`, and `y1`, I want to predict `y2`. Then after observing actual `y2`, given `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, and `y1`, `y2`, I then predict `y3`. **The key here is that this is like an online prediction: At t=3, the actual  `y1` and `y2` is already observed. So the observed values, not the predicted ones, are used to predict `y3`**

[image][image: ![figure]

My question:

Given this [tutorial](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/), I am not sure whether my case should be 'many to one' or 'many to many'.

[image]

If 'many to one', there is nowhere to put `y1` and `y2`. I think `y1` and `y2` should be able to partially determine `y3`. It is possible to add `y1` and `y2` as one input feature in `X1` and `X2`. But there is no way to build `X3` because `y3` is the prediction.

Onthe other hand, for 'many to many', I do not need the prediction of y1 and y2 because they should be known when predicting `y3`.

Comment: Your setup sounds like you want to look at recurrent neural networks.

Comment: You should combine a recurrent neural architecture (e.g. LSTM) with CRFs, here is one example: https://github.com/UKPLab/emnlp2017-bilstm-cnn-crf